# Configuring max-height based on percent of screen

Tags: css

I'm using the following CSS to adjust the height of a scroll box:

```
.scroll 
{
//max-height: 750px;
max-height: 400px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I would like to use 750px, but this is too tall for screens with smaller resolution.  400px works with smaller resolutions, but looks bad on larger screens. Is there a way to specify something like this by percentage? When I try 100%, it breaks my scroll box and uses the entire screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```
@media(max-width:767px){ /* change the max-width to suit your needs */
  .scroll {
    max-height: 400px;
  }
}

@media(min-width:768px){ /* change the min-width to suit your needs */
  .scroll {
    max-height: 750px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of that.  Perfect, did the trick exactly.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use JS or create two CSS files - one for PC and second to another small devices.